# Numbers conditional formatting based on a different cell in the same row

Tags: mac, worksheet-function, spreadsheet, iwork-numbers

I have a Numbers spreadsheet, with "quantity required" and "quantity in stock" columns, then each part is on a row. I'm trying to use conditional formatting to turn a cell yellow when # required = # in stock, i.e. you can only build one widget with the parts you have, and red when # required > # in stock, i.e. you can't build any widgets without first ordering parts. The problem is, Numbers seems to only want to take in individual cells in the conditional formatting box. Is there any formula to tell it, say, when in row 10, turn D10 red if B10 > D10, and the same, B12 and D12 for row 12, and so on, without having to go thru and program each row individually? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Created on a Windows machine but I'm hoping not an issue (though your Excel version might be), the image should indicate one way to achieve what I think you are asking for:

[image: SU528427 example]

You mention "to turn *a* cell" so `Applies to` here is to ColumnD only - A:D might be more useful, as may be adding green highlighting for parts where current stock is sufficient to service quantity required up to its [ROP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reorder_point).

The formulae in conditional formatting rules use arrays, so no need for the tedious repetition your feared!